Выбор предлога: в/на небе
"В/на небе грузно повисло солнце". Что-то совсем не знаю, какой предлог выбрать.

Правильно: В небе грузно повисло солнце.
Пояснение

Значение для предлога В: можно повиснуть в пространстве.

Большой толковый словарь русского языка
ПОВИСНУТЬ, св.  5. Находясь очень высоко, показаться неподвижным или очень слабо движущимся (о птицах, насекомых, небесных светилах, летательных аппаратах). Орёл повис над горами. Солнце повисло над головой. Стрекоза повисла в воздухе. Повисли грозовые облака. Вертолёт повис над реактором.

Сравнить  со значением для предлога НА: можно повиснуть на чем-либо, необходим предмет.

ПОВИСНУТЬ,  св. 1. (нсв. также виснуть). Зацепившись за что-л., удерживаясь на чём-л., свободно свешиваться. На крючке повис лещ. Гимнаст повис на одной руке. Капли дождя повисли на проводах. Пуговица повисла на одной нитке.

Примеры

Солнце висело высоко в небе, длинные пальмы качались из стороны в сторону, а пронизывающий бриз трепал волосы. Ника Светлая, Между нами океан, 2019
Яркое солнце висело высоко в голубом небе, по которому бежали редкие облака. Илья Мордовских, Последний из легенд. #1, 2023
Над городом встало солнце и повисло где-то высоко в синем небе. Антон Наумов. Да, дела // «Дальний Восток», 2019

Sharon, срочно удаляйте/меняйте примеры!.. Не та форма.

Я, конечно, не специалист по примерам, но какая разница, повисло или висело?  Предлоги будут другие?

Я считаю, что в большинстве случаев употребления предлога "В" во фразах о местоположении солнца относительно неба некорректно.
Потому что солнце это не предмет "в небе".
И как верно написано в словаре, "в" это предлог расположение предмета, физ объекта, явления где-то. То есть:
Облака в небе - да.
Отражение луны в луже - да.
Солнце в небе - нет. Солнце на небе корректно.
Однако конкретно здесь, можно обыграть отношение автора к раздражающему объекту, но сделать это лучше через художественный приём, если пойти дальше и заменить "солнце" словом "шар":
В небе грузно повис пылающий шар.
И пусть читатель думает что это за "пылающий шар" повисший в небе, и рисует себе это картину в голове. А автор хитро обошёл реалистичность описания, превратив его в галлюцинацию.

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.
